# Where should userspecific application log files be stored in GNU Linux?

Tags: linux, xdg

This question is about log files produced by simple user applications. The files are specific to the user. Because of that `/var/log` is not a solution here.

I can not find informations about such files in the [XDG Specificiations](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

Where should they be stored by default?

Comment: See for instance these two pages:
https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XDG spec is not very clear on where log files should go. The best fit seems to be under `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` which is for "user specific non-essential data files".

Looking at my local system, there are application logs under all of the `$XDG_*_HOME` locations:

```
$ ls .cache/*/*log
.cache/shotwell/shotwell.log
.cache/simple-scan/simple-scan.log
.cache/virt-manager/virt-clone.log

$ ls .local/share/*/*log
.local/share/FasterThanLight/FTL.log
.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log

$ ls .config/*/*log
.config/VirtualBox/selectorwindow.log
.config/VirtualBox/VBoxSVC.log
```

Using `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` seems wrong, but can see using the (more likely to persist through reboots) `$XDG_DATA_HOME` specifically for applications like Xorg which may break hard enough to require a system restart and want to be able to preserve error logs in these scenarios.

Answer (score 10):

They belong in `$XDG_STATE_HOME` or (as fallback) `~/.local/state`.

When this question was asked, the [then current specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/0.7/ar01s02.html) didn't have `$XDG_STATE_HOME`. It was introduced in 2021 by [Version 0.8](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/0.8/ar01s02.html).

From the current spec:

> $XDG_STATE_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user-specific state files should be stored. If $XDG_STATE_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.local/state should be used.
>
> The $XDG_STATE_HOME contains state data that should persist between (application) restarts, but that is not important or portable enough to the user that it should be stored in $XDG_DATA_HOME. It may contain:
>
> - actions history (logs, history, recently used files, …)
> - current state of the application that can be reused on a restart (view, layout, open files, undo history, …)